# Cannot get body from POST request in Express.js despite using app.use(express.json()) and correct headers

Tags: node.js, api, express, http, postman

I encountered a common problem with Express.js. I cannot get the body from POST request. However, what is different here is that I tried solutions from other posts on Stack Overflow.

I tried:

- changing headers (I send requests from Postman, so it generates correct headers but went through trials)
- added `app.use(express.json())`
- installed, used and uninstalled body-parser package
- tried sending x-www-form-urlencoded (changed headers and `app.use`)
- removed `app.use(cors())`

And it's always the same. No body in the request. I use pino to print logs and what I receive  when I print `req` is:

```
[1629369969516] INFO (78850 on local):
    req: {
      "method": "POST",
      "url": "/test",
      "headers": {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "user-agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.28.3",
        "accept": "*/*",
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "postman-token": "595cd2ce-cfd9-4f8c-b273-55c1baccc6fa",
        "host": "localhost:8002",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "connection": "keep-alive",
        "content-length": "34"
      }
    }
```

This is the excerpt of my code (there are more packages, functions):

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const basicPino = require('pino')
const basicPinoLogger = basicPino({ prettyPrint: true })
const expressPino = require('express-pino-logger')({
  logger: basicPinoLogger
})

const logger = expressPino.logger

const app = express()

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.post('/test', (req, res) => {
    const msg1 = req
    logger.info(msg1)
    res.send("Hi")
}
```

In Postman I receive a response "Hi".

Do you have any ideas on how to fix it and what the problem could be?

Comment: Have you looked at `req.body`? I don't see it mentioned in your sample express code.

Comment: Try using a `logger.debug` instead, maybe the info level omits the request body by default.

Comment: As @O.Jones mentioned, `logger.info(req.body)` will give you the desired result.

Comment: Thank you O.Jones, Hamza Sabljakovic and zx01 ! req.body worked. I did not get that info level omits the body from request.